# How to rename actors in draw.io

Tags: uml, draw, actor, use-case, diagrams.net

I am using draw.io online tool for drawing UML diagrams. When I am dragging an Actor from left panel to the canvas, there I found no options to rename the actor. For example I want to rename the default label 'Actor' to 'User' but no luck. How to rename an Actor?

[image]

Comment: Select the actor and start typing.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Edit: See [Muhammad Toqeer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140696/how-to-rename-actors-in-draw-io/66576537#66576537). Selecting the actor and typing is much easier than double clicking.

Double clicking on the actor seems to do the trick.

[image]

Comment: Easy to do this when it works. But I found it fussy first few times I tried, it created a linked 2nd actor instead, not so intuitive then.

Comment: I knew how to do it then forgot because it didn't seem to do anything the first few times. Thanks!

Comment: Hope they change the way to do that! Because no chance to get it without googling.
Even double clicking on it works! Mmmm.

Answer (score 9):

Very Simple.

1. Add Actor from shapes
2. Select Actor and start typing it will change the name of actor

Comment: This is much easier than double clicking.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to double click on a small actor, so, enlarge it by using Ctrl+Scroll. Then double click to actor text.

Answer (score -2):

Simple, just double click on actor then you can change the text.

[example double click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPz2i.png)

Comment: How does the guidance in this answer differ from the guidance in the accepted answer?

Comment: Well, surprisingly this answer ranks first on Google.